# CISCO ISE COmpactibility with 2960 Switch

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I Was checking the switches which are compatible with Cisco ISE solution, from their site i saw that they support Catalyst 2960-S but in my environment i have 2960-24TC-S, I would like to know what if my switch is compatible and the difference between 2960TC-S and 2960-S.

Comment: Which ISE version are you running?

Comment: Im planning to deploy ISE version 2.4

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the compatibility matrix for Cisco ISE 2.4, your switch is not fully supported. You can also see the difference in relation to ISE between the 2960 and 2960-S.

[image]

Remember for IOS 12.2.55:

The IOS 12.x version does not fully support the Posture and Guest flows because of CSCsx97093. As a workaround, when you configure URL redirect in Cisco ISE, assign a value to “coa-skip-logical-profile.”

Full Cisco ISE 2.4 compatibility matrix:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/2-4/compatibility/b_ise_sdt_24.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably less of a question for the ISE itself, but for the given switch's  802.1x capabilities and additional features.

Most of the advanced 802.1x features need the LAN BASE license, so if your model runs the LAN LITE license, you'd be out of luck when wanting to use these.

Latest IOS available for the 2960-24TC-S is 15.0(2)SE11.  And here's 802.1x configuration guide for that release:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/15-0_2_se/configuration/guide/scg2960/sw8021x.html

(I'll take the blame for a link-only answer here. The configuration guide is just too large to give an excerpt).